# Reverse Link Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using asp.net 4.5.1 webform with EF codefirst; 
There is two class of Product and category; each product can have many categories. and each category can have many products. when I want select all the products in the selected categories by user, I use :

```
List<int> CatId = new List<int>(); 
// add all the selected category Id to the CatId list.   
_db.Categories.Where(p => CatId.Contains(p.CategoryID)).SelectMany(p => p.Products);
```

this code work goods. my question is that how can I write this query in the reverse view?
Let me explain more, this code is selecting the categories that user selected then select all the products in those category.(from category view)
but I want do this from Product View, it means first select products then check that product is in that category or not.

I know the result of both query is same. but I need to do this.

Comment: How product and category related in your code? Please show keys and/or navigation properties you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If product has only one category:

```
_db.Products.Where(p => CatId.Contains(p.Category.CategoryID));
```

If product can have multiple categories:

```
_db.Products.Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c => CatId.Contains(c.CategoryID)));
```

Consider also renaming categories ids list to `categoryIds` to show that it is a collection of ids, not single id.